# Function return value not showing in console - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 js files named as *rep_customerDetails.js* and *BackendReports.js*.

In *rep_customerDetails.js* has below code.

```
import firebase from '../../../../fbConfig/fbConfig'

export const rep_customerDetails = (inputs) => {
    var data = [];
    var count = 1;
    firebase.firestore().collection('customer').get()
        .then((snap) => {
            snap.forEach((doc) => {
                data.push(doc.data())
                if (count == snap.docs.length) {
                    console.log(data)
                    return data
                }
                count++
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            return (err)
        })
}
```

I call this function from *BackendReports.js* file and below the code.

```
    //On search button click
    const generateReport = () => {
        switch (inputs.reportName) {
            case "Customer details":
                const x = rep_customerDetails(inputs);
                console.log(x)
                break;
            case "Delivery details":
                break;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

This shows me 2 console results. 1st one is **undefined** and second one is the expected output of firestore. Undefined value display from the *BackendReports.js* file. Why is this happenning? Why return values not showing in the console.

Refer the console log result. [console SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhYDp.png)

Comment: `rep_customerDetails` doesn't return anything other then an implicit `undefined` void return.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function with forEach returns undefined even with return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392445/function-with-foreach-returns-undefined-even-with-return-statement)

Comment: Is this function supposed to be asynchronous?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)