# How to chain multiple array methods to arrow function

Tags: javascript, foreach, mapping

In my arrow function I'm trying to use method .forEach and then chain .map method to it, but I'm getting **error message** `"(card).map(card => {"` "card is not defined".

I also tried using .find method `const findCards = cards.find(card => card.symbol === '7' ).map(card => {` **error message** "map is not a function"

I was able to chain .map method to a .filter method.

```
const filteredCards = cards.filter(card => card.number).map(card => {
```

I'm able to console log .forEach without the .map.. SO I'm confused a bit..

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="forEach-method"></div>
<div class="container" id="find-method"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
const cards = [
{  symbol: '1', number: true},
{  symbol: '2', number: true},
{  symbol: '3', number: true},
{  symbol: '4', number: true},
{  symbol: '5', number: true},
{  symbol: '6', number: true},
{  symbol: '7', number: true},
{  symbol: '8', number: true},
{  symbol: '9', number: true},
{  symbol: '+', number: false},   
{  symbol: '-', number: false},   
{  symbol: '*', number: false} 
];


//.FOREACH METHOD
const cardsContainerforEach = document.querySelector('#forEach-method');
const forEachCards = cards.forEach(card).map(card => {
  return '<div class="card">' + '<span>' + card.symbol + '<span>' + '</div>';
})
cardsContainerforEach.innerHTML = forEachCards.join('\n');


//.FIND METHOD
const cardsContainerFind = document.querySelector('#find-method');
const findCards = cards.find(card => card.symbol === '7' ).map(card => {
  return '<div class="card">' + '<span>' + card.symbol + '<span>' + '</div>';
})
cardsContainerFind.innerHTML = findCards.join('\n');
```

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything so cannot be chained. You can only chain if the method you wish to use exists on the thing being returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function with forEach returns undefined even with return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392445/function-with-foreach-returns-undefined-even-with-return-statement)

Comment: You can do it by simulating a forEach chain, if you are keen on chaining forEach. Do you want that?

Comment: Also, in your case, you don't need the forEach unless you want to perform specific operations on the array using the forEach.

Comment: Basically, I've been on the learning stages and trying to understand why it's not allowing me to chain .map to these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreach don't return anything, thats why you cant chain it, and find returns a single object not an array, thats why you can't chain that.
You can chain .map method to a .filter method because map returns an array.

The line `cards.forEach(card)` is looking for a function named card. What you probably are trying is to inject a fatarrow function into foreach, that should look like this `cards.forEach(card => /* do something with card */)`.

```js
const cards = [
{  symbol: '1', number: true},
{  symbol: '2', number: true},
{  symbol: '3', number: true},
{  symbol: '4', number: true},
{  symbol: '5', number: true},
{  symbol: '6', number: true},
{  symbol: '7', number: true},
{  symbol: '8', number: true},
{  symbol: '9', number: true},
{  symbol: '+', number: false},   
{  symbol: '-', number: false},   
{  symbol: '*', number: false} 
];

const foreach = cards.forEach(card => card);
const find = cards.find(card => card.symbol === '-');
const map = cards.map(card => parseInt(card.symbol));

console.log('forEach:', foreach); // Should return undefined.
console.log('find:', find); // Should return a single object.
console.log('map:', map); // Should return an array object.

//.filter() METHOD
const filterCards = cards.filter(card => !card.number ).map(card => {
  return '<div class="card">' + '<span>' + card.symbol + '<span>' + '</div>';
})
console.log(filterCards.join('\n'));
```

Of the options that you tried only map returns an array meaning that you have the higher order array functions available on map.

Comment: That's very well explained, thank you.

What about these methods , do they returns array?
1).some method
2).every method
3).reduce method
4).includes method

Comment: 1) `.some()` returns a boolean, and returns first time it hits a true 2) `every()` runs through all of the elements and see if they are all true, return a boolean. 3) `.reduce()` returns an array, it's usually used to reduce the array, 4) `.includes` looks if an element is in the array, returns a boolean.

Comment: Can I chain .map to these 4 methods?

Comment: You can chain `.map` after `.reduce` (3), the other functions returns a boolean, and will not be chainable to `.map`.  You can chain all these after `.map` tho.

Comment: Jacob, that the exact answer I was looking for!
Thank you so much for your time.

Can you also please struncture the arrow function below that I'm chaining .find method to a .map method. so I can have it as a refference.

const findCards = cards.find(card => card.symbol === '7' ).map(card => {

Comment: Sure thing, you need to use `.filter` insted of `.find`, since `.find` only returns a single object, `.filter` returns a new array of objects that satisfy the conditional in the fat arrow function. I have updated the answer with a filter example.

Answer (score 1):

So I can see two issues here.

1. You don't need the `forEach` on your first function. `map` will iterate over the  array and return a new array with the contents changed as you've asked.
2. `find` returns an element, not an array, so you'd be better off using either `filter`, then mapping over it, or just returning the result of find and passing it to html.

Here's your code returning what you want by mapping over the filter (good if you expect cases with more than one result)...

```
const cards = [
  {  symbol: '1', number: true},
  {  symbol: '2', number: true},
  {  symbol: '3', number: true},
  {  symbol: '4', number: true},
  {  symbol: '5', number: true},
  {  symbol: '6', number: true},
  {  symbol: '7', number: true},
  {  symbol: '8', number: true},
  {  symbol: '9', number: true},
  {  symbol: '+', number: false},   
  {  symbol: '-', number: false},   
  {  symbol: '*', number: false} 
];

//.FOREACH METHOD
const cardsContainerforEach = document.querySelector('#forEach-method');
const forEachCards = cards.map(card => {
  return '<div class="card">' + '<span>' + card.symbol + '<span>' + '</div>';
})
cardsContainerforEach.innerHTML = forEachCards.join('\n');

//.FIND METHOD
const cardsContainerFind = document.querySelector('#find-method');
const findCards = cards.filter(card => card.symbol === '7').map(card => {
  return '<div class="card">' + '<span>' + card.symbol + '<span>' + '</div>';
})

cardsContainerFind.innerHTML = findCards.join('\n');
```

Comment: Paul, Thank you for your time.
I'm actually on the learning stages and trying to understand why is not letting me to chain another method (.map). I'm sure there is better ways of doing it.

Comment: No worries! When you chain 2 methods, the first will return something and the second will operate on what the first returned. With your forEach method, forEach doesn't return anything, so your map function isn't mapping on anything and is therefore throwing the error. With your find method, it is returning {  symbol: '7', number: true}, so the map method cannot map over it.

Comment: So should I begin my arrow function with .map method - for other methods to work?

Comment: You can chain any method that returns something, here's a codepen with some explanations...
https://codepen.io/paulmartin91/pen/gOgNaxv?editors=0011

Comment: Paul, you're a legend. Thanks a lot!