# Why does forEach return undefined?

Tags: javascript, foreach, undefined

Here is my code to solve leetcode- Two sum

```js
let nums = [2, 7, 11, 15];
let  target = 9;
for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  let x = target - nums[i];
  if (nums[i + 1] === x) {
    console.log([i, i+1]) // [0, 1]
    return [i, i + 1];
  }
}  //it ok
```

```
nums.forEach((item, index) => {
  let x = target - nums[index];
  if (nums[index + 1] === x) {
    console.log([index, index + 1]);// [0, 1]
    return [index,index+1]
  }
}); // undefined
```

I use `forEach` instead of `for(...)`, both console.log are same, but `forEach` returns `undefined`. Why?

Comment: May you also share the forEach version as a [mcve]?

Comment: The `Array.prototype.forEach` always returns `undefined`. You cannot return anything from that function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value

Comment: @SajeebAhamed then he can use `Array.prototype.map`

Comment: @MMD the OP's purpose is completely different. He wants only one result out of the array. Map for modifying every elements.

Comment: sorry, I updated. and thanks to tell me

Comment: @wangg does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392445/function-with-foreach-returns-undefined-even-with-return-statement

Comment: Thanks. I got it. `forEach` don't return anything. in my question, `map` or `for`  are better choice than `forEach` .

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
because the forEach always return  `undefined`

```
let nums = [2, 7, 11, 15],
  target = 9;
let m = {};
nums.map((value, index) => {
  m[value] = index;
});

for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  let diff = target - nums[i];
  if (m.hasOwnProperty(diff)) {
    console.log(i, m[diff]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example

Comment: thank you , I will try it