# Javascript recursive function seemingly working but returning 'undefined' object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I wrote a recursive function such as:
**Note :** you might not need to understand the nuts and bolts to help as it already looks like it does what I want

```js
const rec = (arg_array, an_array, condition_state_out, state = 0) => {
  if (state < condition_state_out) {
    an_array.forEach((ele) => {
      an_array.shift();
      return rec([...arg_array, ele], an_array, condition_state_out, state + 1);
    });
  } else {
    console.log(arg_array);
    return arg_array;
  }
};
```

When I run it,

```js
const returned = rec([], an_array, condition_state_out, 0)
```

through the log, I see that it builds exactly what I want, so it is **seemingly correct**.

But when I check the returned object

```js
console.log(returned)
```

It is `undefined`

I really can't figure out what is wrong as the complex part looks like it is working...

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Thanks. I tried (before) with the return also in the if statement part and it does not change anything. I edited accordingly

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] (with sample contents of `an_array` and `condition_state_out`), as well as the expected outcome?

Comment: I agree that it looks exactly like the other post... I will come up with something to reproudce

Comment: Maybe it does not get into the forEach, i' ll check

Comment: Ah right. Missed that part. See [Function with forEach returns undefined even with return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392445/function-with-foreach-returns-undefined-even-with-return-statement)