# Handle return statement in a better way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, cycle

That's my function:

```
 const checkifHaveBomb = (column, row) => {
            let isBomb = false
            activeBombContainer.forEach(element => {

                if (element.column === column && element.row === row) {
                    isBomb = true;
                    return;
                }
            })
            if (isBomb) return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

This was my 1st try:

```
 const checkifHaveBomb = (column, row) => {

            activeBombContainer.forEach(element => {
                if (element.column === column && element.row === row) {
                   
                    return true;
                }
            })
            
            return false;
        }
```

I was thinking that returns will end the function, but i didnt work.
I suppose that the return statement is applied to forEach instead of checkifHaveBomb .

There is a better way to write this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function with forEach returns undefined even with return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392445/function-with-foreach-returns-undefined-even-with-return-statement)

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

`return` ends the function, `forEach` just calls a function for each element

### Solutions

#### Some

You can try using `some` and return `true` if you want to finish:

```
const checkifHaveBomb = (column, row) => {
  let isBomb = false
  activeBombContainer.some(element => {

    if (element.column === column && element.row === row) {
      isBomb = true;
      return true;
    }
  })
  if (isBomb) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
const checkifHaveBomb = (column, row) => {
  return activeBombContainer.some(element => {
    if (element.column === column && element.row === row) {
      isBomb = true;
      return true;
    }
  })
}
```

#### loop statement

You can also just use a normal `for..of` loop

```
const checkifHaveBomb = (column, row) => {
  for (const element of activeBombContainer) {
    if (element.column === column && element.row === row) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `forEach`.

```
const checkifHaveBomb = (column, row)
=> activeBombContainer.some( element=>element.column === column && element.row === row);
```

As you surmised, the return value of `Array.prototype/forEach`'s argument function is discarded after each call.

Answer (score 0):

You want to iterate through the `activeBombContainer` array until the condition returns `true`. Sounds like [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function might suit your needs:

> The find() method returns the first element in the provided array that
> satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the
> testing function, undefined is returned.

You should be able to write the function as follows

```
checkifHaveBomb = (column, row) => {
    return activeBombContainer.find(element => {
        return element.column === column && element.row === row
    })
}
```

Alternatively you could use the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function because it returns a `boolean` value.

```
checkifHaveBomb = (column, row) => {
    return activeBombContainer.some(element => {
        return element.column === column && element.row === row
    })
}
```