# Array methods returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is something I still don't quite understand very well, I have the following situation:

> ```
> // #2) Check if this array includes any name that has "John" inside of it. If it does, return that 
> // name or names in an array. 
> const dragons = ['Tim', 'Johnathan', 'Sandy', 'Sarah'];
> ```

at first I tried the following:

```
const name = dragons.forEach(element => {
    element.includes("John") ? element : null
});
```

it returns `undefined`

then:

```
const name = dragons.filter(element => {
    element.includes("John");
});
```

it returns an empty array

then:

```
function name() {
    const dragons = ['Tim', 'Johnathan', 'Sandy', 'Sarah'];
    dragons.forEach(element => {
        if (element.includes("John")) {
            return element;
        }
    });
}
```

again it returns `undefined`

but the interesting thing is that if on any of the attempts I change the action to do to `console.log(element);` then it will show "Johnathan" which is the correct output.

so it means that the logic is working, I just don't understand why it won't return the value if I want to let's say assign it to a variable.

I even tried the following:

```
const dragons = ['Tim', 'Johnathan', 'Sandy', 'Sarah'];

dragons.forEach(element => {
    if (element.includes("John")) {
        const name = element;
    }
});
```

but it again returns name as `undefined`, why is that?

edit: this was my first stack overflow question, really I wasn't expecting someone answering my question, I thought maybe it was a dumb question or that i didn't explained myself well but it was very nice to find such a supportive community, thank you so much to all of you who commented and helped me!

Comment: Things will become easier when you grasp the difference between `element => { element.includes("John"); }` and `element => element.includes("John")`. One of the two works, the other doesn't.

Comment: "*at first I tried the following*" `forEach` always returns `undefined`. Even if you return a value in the callback, which you don't. For the second attempt see: [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28889450). For the third: [Function with forEach returns undefined even with return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16392445). For the fourth: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431).

Comment: You are reinventing `some()` or `every()`

Comment: Ohh, I tried: ```const name = dragons.filter(element => element.includes("John"));``` and now it outputs the correct result, so the mistake was to include the curly brackets and the ; after the statement? thank you so much @WiktorZychla for clarifying!

Comment: return an array of `["John", "John", "John"]` or?... Could you explain your exact task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` method does return `undefined`. But `filter` instead returns the array but filtered. However, the problem is that you are forgetting to return the values inside it.

To fix it try:

```
const name = dragons.filter(element => {
  return element.includes("John");
});
```

Or:

```
const name = dragons.filter(element => element.includes("John"));
```

Comment: the method "includes" is not defined on element, which is a string. It is defined only on the array. so it should rather be `filter(element => element == "John")`

Comment: @Sebastian "*the method "includes" is not defined on element, which is a string.*" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes ???

Comment: `includes` is a method of the `String`. Also, if you check `element == "John"` would be incorrect because we want to check a subtring inside a `string`

Comment: Oh, double sorry, both your comments are correct, my bad.

Comment: it seems that I was missing the return keyword on the filter method, I forgot I had to use it I thought it automatically returned if the condition resolved to true. thank you so much! now I understand.

Answer (score 2):

First, `forEach` *never*  returns anything. You'd need a `map` for that, or `filter` (what are you exactly after?). Second, your callback functions don't return anything, either. You can map or filter your array like that:

```
const dragonsNamedJohn = dragons.filter(name => name.includes('John'));
```

or

```
const dragonsNamedJohn = dragons.filter(name => {
    return name.includes('John'); 
});
```

or even

```
function hisNameIsJohn (name) {
    return name.includes('John');
}

const dragonsNamedJohn = dragons.filter(hisNameIsJohn);
```

(You might want to stick `toLowerCase()` somewhere there, or not, dependent on whether you want the comparison to be case-sensitive. Also, another way of skinning a dragon would be to use a regular expression).

Comment: These solutions compare only the entire `string`, they do not check if a value is inside a `string`, so they are not the correct solutions.

Comment: But... the task is to return an Array (of all the names) - if "John" was not found. Otherwise, return the String "John"? OR I misunderstood... perhaps the task if to return `["John", "John", "John"]` if multiple "John" are present in the original Array...?

Comment: Thank you for the other ways to solve the problem, I understand now that I must use the return keyword if I'm using the curly brackets inside the arrow function in the method, I was confused, thank you for clarifying!