# Filter an array within an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of 10 users, I want to filter the users based on the 'intresses' (that means interests in dutch) array within the users. So for example I want to filter all the users that have the interests 'Afrika' (like index 2).

This is what I tried but it will give me an empty array back.

```
var newArray = gesorteerdeMatchPercentages.filter((el) => {
        el.intresses.forEach((item) => {
          return item.naam === "Afrika";
        });
      });

      console.log("new", newArray);
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `===`? There is no reason whatsoever for _you_ to do use `===` in the type of code you're writing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function with forEach returns undefined even with return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392445/function-with-foreach-returns-undefined-even-with-return-statement)

Comment: You're accessing `item.naam` but the screenshot shows the property is named `Intresse_naam`. You'll probably want to use a regex as well since that data seems to be somewhat sketchy, e.g., at least one value includes escaped characters.

Comment: `forEach` does nothing w/ return values; you need to return something from `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you could do that using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this

```
var newArray = gesorteerdeMatchPercentages.filter((el) => {
 return el.intresses.some(el => el.naam === 'Afrika'); 
});
```